# How to group data by specific time window, where second time is next day

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I need to calculate sum of some events between 2015-01-01 and 2015-12-31 made every night between 21:30 and 04:30 next day?

How to made it by using Pandas in a most elegant but possible simple and efficient way?

Example results table should look similar to the following:

```
             count   
2015-04-01      38   (events between 2015-03-31 21:30 and 2015-04-01 04:30)
2015-04-02      15   (events between 2015-04-01 21:30 and 2015-04-02 04:30)
2015-04-03      27   (events between 2015-04-02 21:30 and 2015-04-03 04:30)
```

Thanks for any help and suggestions.

Comment: you should put a sample of your data

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':['2015-04-01 15:00','2015-04-01 23:00','2015-04-01 04:00','2015-04-02 03:00','2015-05-02 16:00','2015-04-03 02:00'],
                   'b':[2,4,3,1,7,10]})
df['a'] = pd.to_datetime(df.a)
```

```
print (df)
                    a   b
0 2015-04-01 15:00:00   2
1 2015-04-01 23:00:00   4
2 2015-04-01 04:00:00   3
3 2015-04-02 03:00:00   1
4 2015-05-02 16:00:00   7
5 2015-04-03 02:00:00  10
```

Create `DatetimeIndex`:

```
start = pd.to_datetime('2015-04-01')
d = pd.date_range(start, periods=3)
print (d)
DatetimeIndex(['2015-04-01', '2015-04-02', '2015-04-03'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='D')
```

Loop by `DatetimeIndex`, select all rows by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and get `len`:

```
for dat in d:
    date_sum = len(df.ix[(df.a >= dat.date()+pd.offsets.DateOffset(hours=21, minutes=30)) & 
                (df.a <= dat.date()+pd.offsets.DateOffset(days=1, hours=4, minutes=30)),'b'])
    print (date_sum)
    print (dat.date())
2
2015-04-01
1
2015-04-02
0
```

Create new `Series` by dict comprehension:

```
out = { dat.date(): len(df.ix[(df.a >= dat.date() + pd.offsets.DateOffset(hours=21, minutes=30)) & (df.a <= dat.date() + pd.offsets.DateOffset(days=1, hours=4, minutes=30)), 'b']) for dat in d}
s = pd.Series(out)
print (s)
2015-04-01    2
2015-04-02    1
2015-04-03    0
dtype: int64
```

Comment: i like it. i just wonder if this is not too slow when the data is huge.. great job anyway

Comment: Thank you. It looks like very complicated, but I believe with data from OP it can be simplier.